# Mouse.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed never returning true

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a Windows Forms Application in C# which monitors if the mouse buttons are being held down. There is a primary thread for the GUI, which spawns a secondary STA thread. This code never executes within it:

```
 if (Mouse.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
 {
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Left mouse down");
 }
```

I wondered if this is because I have the following STA option enabled for the thread?

```
 repeaterThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
 repeaterThread.Start();
```

Full relevant code:
I'm using `PresentationCore.dll`, and `System.Windows.Input`;
Winforms GUI:

On start button pressed:

```
 ...
 Thread repeaterThread = new Thread(() => ListenerThread());
 repeaterThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
 repeaterThread.Start();
 ...
```

ListenerThread method:

```
public static void ListenerThread()
{
   while(true)
   {
      if (Mouse.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
      {
         System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Left mouse down");
      }
      Thread.sleep(1000);
   }
}
```

How can I capture if the mouse button is being held down from this thread?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to call `Application.Run()` inside `ListenerThread()` before the loop?

Comment: Just tried it, didn't work. Empty context on the Run() right?

Comment: yes. You call Run() without parameters in order to start message loop for current thread

Comment: Yeah, I did try that, no luck :(

Comment: Wait, are you trying to mix winforms and wpf?

Comment: Maybe...I'm using the WPF PresentationCore.dll at least? Does that count?

Comment: The Mouse class requires the WPF dispatcher loop to provide accurate information.  The diagnostic here is that your app runs the Winforms dispatcher loop.  In other words, wrong Application.Run().  Swapping it is no solution, now Winforms gets wonky and you, for example, notice that navigation and shortcut keys no longer works.  Displaying UI on more than one thread is generally also a rather bad idea, you get to debug [problems like this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsui_team/archive/2012/10/31/debugging-windows-forms-application-hangs-during-systemevents.userpreferencechanged.aspx).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to mix two GUI technologies: WinForms and WPF. You've set environment suitable for WinForms but trying to use methods from WPF.

You dont need `PresentationCore.dll` and `System.Windows.Input`. The desired result can be achieved using `System.Windows.Forms.Control` class:

```
public static void ListenerThread()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if ((Control.MouseButtons & MouseButtons.Left) == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Left mouse down");
        }
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Having just tested this, it doesn't work. I am using System.Windows.Forms.Control as you suggested, copied and pasted your code exactly.

Comment: Works fine here. Maybe you press mouse while your thread sleeps? And make sure you are starting your thread before `Application.Run()` is called

Comment: Hmm, I have my thread created and started from within the Form class, so when a user presses a button, it creates and starts the thread from the : Form class ( I.e. the GUI code behind ). So the Application.Run() always takes place before the Thread is even created. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Ok, worked it out, sorry, your suggestion of Control.MouseButtons worked first time. I just messed it up with my code. I wasn't hitting the correct code path. Thank you very much, marked as answer!